# Which inside of Do: strange behavior

Tags: list-manipulation

My question is about the use of "Which" inside "Do". More precisely, I have written these two pieces of code, which I think should give the same answer. I define a list:

```
part = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}
lenpart=Length[part];
```

Then I print the elements of the list. I do it first like this:

```
Do[Which[
ipart==1,
Print[part[[ipart]]],
ipart!=1 && ipart!=lenpart,
Print[part[[ipart]]],
ipart==lenpart,
Print[part[[ipart]]]
],{ipart,1,lenpart}];
```

This one prints all the elements of the list, as I would expect. Then I do it in this way:

```
Do[Which[
ipart==First[part],
Print[ipart],
ipart!=First[part] && ipart!=Last[part],
Print[ipart],
ipart==Last[part],
Print[ipart]
],{ipart,part}];
```

This one, instead, prints only `{a,b}`, but it seems to me that they should give the same output. I am using Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that mathematica does not know if {a,b}!={c,d}. So this is not evaluated as true since c could be the same value as a, and so on.

```
Table[ipart != {a, b}, {ipart, part}]
```

> {False, {c, d} != {a, b}, {e, f} != {a, b}, {g, h} != {a, b}}